# boost::variant and std::find_if

Tags: c++, c++98

How do I use a visitor with the find_if function? I'm guessing I need to do some class of magical bind and therefore this will not work:

```
    typedef boost::variant<FileNode,DirectoryNode> Node;
    typedef std::vector<Node> Nodes;
    const Nodes& nodes;
    IsFileNodeVisitor isFileNodeVisitor;
    find_if (nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), isFileNodeVisitor);

    class IsFileNodeVisitor: public boost::static_visitor<bool>
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const FileNode&) const {
            return true;
        }

        bool operator()(const DirectoryNode&) const {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

The idea of the code above is to give me an iterator to the first FileNode instance in the vector of nodes.

Comment: If you call `apply_visitor`, it will execute the the code with the correct type, there is no iteration as you are trying above. A variadic type only holds a single instance (of one of it's types.)

Comment: May be you ought to indicate what you are attempting, `find_if` in this context has no use (if it wasn't clear from my first comment..)

Comment: Your code does not align with your question - hence the confusion, you don't appear to have a `vector` of nodes, just a single instance of the `variant`.

Comment: @Nim: there is just a missing declaration of what "Nodes" are. But you can guess that "Nodes" are a std container of Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that using [boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html) should work :

```
 std::find_if (nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
               boost::bind(&boost::apply_visitor<IsFileNodeVisitor,Node>,
                           IsFileNodeVisitor(), _1 )
              );
```